# Adjective for adult children

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives, american-english, british-english

Is there an adjective in English to describe grown-up children? In context, I was writing about family dynamics and the "parental duty of care" towards children, but got stuck on a word describing any duty of care of adult children towards their (elderly) parents.

Example sentence:

> The mother and father have a parental duty of care, especially in their offspring's younger years. In return the children have a *{adjective for adult children}* duty of care to their elderly parents in later years.

Obviously candidates like "infantile" or "juvenile" don't work as they exclude *adult* children.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: In general I'd advise against accepting an answer straight away. Fewer people tend to visit answered questions, so you may get other, better, answers if you leave it a day or two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider the word **[filial](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/filial)**:

> of, relating to, or befitting a son or daughter: *filial obedience*

<sup>dictionary.com</sup>

This word doesn't connotate *adult* children as such, but unlike your rejected words of "infantile" and "juvenile" it doesn't connotate under-18s.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more formal word, you can use [issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=issue&oq=issue&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i61l3.861j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> children of one's own.
>   "he died without male issue"

Usually this is used in formal settings, such as legal or historical documents.